# Lost passphrase recovery for SSL

Tags: ssl, openssl

Today is friday and I'm a desperate sysadmin. I issued a demand of certificate for an HTTPS server, and just received it after more than a long week of waiting, but while my request was processed I lost the passphrase that secured my private key.

Given that I have the private key and the public key jointly generated with the passphrase (that I knew by the time), could there be a clever way to recover the lost passphrase.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This was closed because it is duplicate of http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17759/lost-passphrase-recovery-for-ssl#comment28839_17759.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. The point of these protection is precisely to make it infeasible to recover the password.

If the password wasn't too long, you might try brute force...

Your best option is probably to contact your CA and ask them to re-issue a certificate with a new CSR. Some might allow re-keying without an extra fee during the certificate validity period.

Comment: Thanks, better to know there is no hope than hoping for nothing. ;) I did send the demand, I'll see this on monday I guess. :( (european timezone, week end is starting here).

Comment: Just in case, you could check whether the private key you've generated was encrypted. It depends on where it's stored. If it's in a PEM file that starts with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and contains the word `ENCRYPTED` after, it's a bad sign...

Comment: Bad sign confirmed: -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,ED5585270224041E